# How to group multiple lists using LINQ - Sum and GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have three generic lists and I am trying to combine and get them into one (`List<One>`). I am not sure how to use LINQ group by on different lists. I want to group by AccountCode, AccountDate, and SalesCode; and sum the amount.

```
public class One
{
    public string AccountCode { get; set; }

    public DateTime AccountDate { get; set; }

    public string SalesCode { get; set; }

    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
}

public class Two
{
    public string AccountCode { get; set; }

    public DateTime AccountDate { get; set; }

    public string SalesCode { get; set; }

    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
}   

public class Three
{
    public string AccountCode { get; set; }

    public DateTime AccountDate { get; set; }

    public string SalesCode { get; set; }

    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
}   

List<One> oneList = new List<One>();
List<Two> twoList = new List<Two>();
List<Three> threeList = new List<Three>();
```

This is the sample query I have, which is not working. Note: I have not included `List<Three>`.

```
from first in oneList
    join second in twoList
    on first.AccountCode equals second.AccountCode
    where
    (first.AccountDate.Date == second.AccountDate.Date && first.SalesCode == second.SalesCode)
     select new
     {
         first.AccountCode,
         first.AccountDate,
         first.SalesCode
         first.Amount,
         second.Amount
     }).Distinct()
                group bill by new { bill.AccountCode, bill.AccountDate, bill.SalesCode }
    into groupedList
    select new  
    {
        groupedList.Key.UAN,
        groupedList.Key.AccountDate,
        Amount = groupedList.Sum(a => a.Amount)
    };
```

Comment: Sounds like, One, Two, Three should be inherited from a base class (`Account`). Then you can work on `IEnuerbale<Account>`.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. Do you want to join the lists as in a sql join or combined them (union)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the first thing you'll need is a common type so that the 3 lists can be joined into a single list. That could be a base class or an interface as I've shown here.

```
public interface IAccount
{
    string AccountCode { get; set; }
    DateTime AccountDate { get; set; }
    string SalesCode { get; set; }
    decimal? Amount { get; set; }
}

public class One : IAccount 
{
    // ...
}

public class Two : IAccount 
{
    // ...
}

public class Three : IAccount 
{
    // ...
}
```

Once that's in place, then it's easy to combine your 3 lists into one like this:

```
var allList = oneList.Cast<IAccount>().Union(twoList).Union(threeList);
```

From there, the group by becomes much simpler as well. When using LINQ to group by multiple fields, you'll want an `IEqualityComparer` class that looks like this:

```
public class AccountComparer : IEqualityComparer<IAccount>
{

    public bool Equals(IAccount x, IAccount y)
    {
        return x.AccountCode == y.AccountCode &&
            x.AccountDate == y.AccountDate &&
            x.SalesCode == y.SalesCode;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IAccount obj)
    {
        return (obj.AccountCode + obj.AccountDate + obj.SalesCode).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The group by call is then one line:

```
var groups = allList.GroupBy(a => a, new AccountComparer());
```

Alternatively, you could create an `AccountKey` class that only has the 3 key fields and return that from the `keySelector` lambda. That feels a little cleaner, but is a bit more code.

From there, you can select the sums like this:

```
var amountSums = from g in groups
    select new
    {
        g.Key.AccountCode,
        g.Key.AccountDate,
        g.Key.SalesCode,
        Amount = g.Sum(a => a.Amount)
    };
```